# Fetch blob content by blob URI from Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-logic-apps

What is the best-practice to fetch a blobs content in a Azure Logic App if I want to use the blob URi?

Example uri: https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/blobcontainer/filename

[image]

I can't use ["Get blob content (V2)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#get-blob-content-(v2)) or "[Get blob content using path (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#get-blob-content-using-path-(v2))" since I need to give either an ID or the path in the container e.g.: myfolder\myfile.xml

Using a HTTP shape with GET operation on the URi works fine but seems like a hassle since I would need another operation just to fetch the content from the HTTP body.

Suggestions?

Comment: why not adding a operation to split the url so you can extract path ?

Comment: @Houssem I could this of course but I'd like to keep the number of actions down if possible

Comment: @DrejarN, you can't have everything, you have to work with what's available and you've outlined the options yourself.